# Непонятная bash команда «доллар ухо амперсанд»

Tags: linux, bash

Что означает следующая команда в определении функции?

`$@&`

Answer (score 4):

> `$@ &`

1. `$@` — это обращение к специальному параметру `@`, который разворачивается в список всех аргументов, переданных скрипту/функции.
2. `&` — это один из управляющих операторов (*control operator*), служащий в качестве разделителя команд — `команда1 & команда2`. но, в отличие от, например, оператора `;`, `команда1` будет запущена в фоновом режиме, а выполнение `команды2` начнётся **сразу же**, без ожидания завершения `команды1`.

---

пример:

```
f() {
  $@ &
  echo test
}
f какая-нибудь команда с аргументами
```

при запуске начнётся выполнение в фоновом режиме `какой-нибудь команды с аргументами`, и сразу (до её завершения, если она отработает не мгновенно, конечно) будет выполнена команад `echo test`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$@
```

Все позициональные параметры, буквально (без интерпретации или расширения).

```
&
```

Выполнить в заднем плане.

Это значит, что например если скрипт `something.sh` был вызванный командой

```
./something one two three
```

то

```
$@&
```

выполнит команду

```
one two three
```

в заднем плане.